# Solve system differential equations (Sun and Jupiter trajectories)

Tags: python, plot, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations and find the trajectory of Sun and Jupiter. But I don't have a nice trajectory, only some points.
Could you help? ("Soleil" means Sun)

[image]

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint   
from mc_deriv import deriv

start = 0
end   = 14*365
nbpas = end/10
t = np.linspace(start,end,nbpas)
M = M_Soleil + M_Jupiter

x0    = x_Jupiter  - x_Soleil
y0    = y_Jupiter  - y_Soleil
vx0   = vx_Jupiter - vx_Soleil
vy0   = vy_Jupiter - vy_Soleil

syst_CI = [x0,y0,vx0,vy0]               
Sols=odeint(deriv,syst_CI,t,args=(M,))  

x  = Sols[:, 0]           
y  = Sols[:, 1]
vx = Sols[:, 2]
vy = Sols[:, 3]
```

The initialisation

```
x_Soleil    = -7.139143380212696e-03       # (UA)
y_Soleil    = -2.792019770161695e-03       # (UA)
x_Jupiter   = +3.996321311604079e+00       # (UA)
y_Jupiter   = +2.932561211517850e+00       # (UA)

vx_Soleil   = -7.139143380212696e-03       # (UA*j^-1)
vy_Soleil   = -2.792019770161695e-03       # (UA*j^-1)
vx_Jupiter  = +3.996321311604079e+00       # (UA*j^-1)
vy_Jupiter  = +2.932561211517850e+00       # (UA*j^-1)

M_Soleil    = 2e30                         # masse Soleil  (kg)
M_Jupiter   = 1.9e27                       # masse Jupiter (kg)
r_Soleil    = 696e6                        # rayon Soleil  (m)
```

And the outer function

```
def deriv(syst,t,M):
    G     = 6.67e-11 
    x     = syst[0]
    y     = syst[1]
    vx    = syst[2]
    vy    = syst[3]
    dxdt  = vx
    dydt  = vy
    dvxdt = -(G*M*x)/((x**2+y**2)**(3/2))
    dvydt = -(G*M*y)/((x**2+y**2)**(3/2))
    return dxdt,dydt,dvxdt,dvydt
```

The plot

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
plt.title("Trajectoires Soleil-Jupiter")
#plt.xlabel("UA)")
#plt.ylabel("UA)")
plt.plot(x,  y,  '-', color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image: Variables]

[image]

The result of the plot :[image]

Eureka it works!!!!

[image]

Comment: At the moment, your error is not reproducible. It is not clear what your expected results and the obtained results are.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I see the following problems in your code that render your observations unreproducible (apart from missing reference values):

- In the initial data, the length unit is the astronomical unit and the time unit is one day. The unit of the gravitational constant is `m^3 s^-1 kg^-2`, so to combine them in one formula you need to convert AU into m, the factor is about `150e+09`, of which the cube is to be divided out. And one day is `24*3600` seconds, which has to be multiplied in.
- The integration time interval should also be counted in years, at the moment you seem to think of days, a third unit without appropriate conversion factors. [*solved, un jour=one day*]
- From the division in the construction of the time nodes it appears as if you use python 2. Then the exponents `3/2` evaluate to `1` in integer division, you can directly use `1.5` in the exponent, it is an exact value in the binary floating point format. [*actually python 3, then the first division should be explicitly integer*]
- In copying the initial data you made a copy-paste error, the initial positions and velocities have the same numbers, while the real numbers should form perpendicular vectors. [not solved in code, image has correct velocities] Looking for online data that fits your position, the NASA HORIZON system gives me for `2011-Nov-11 04:00` the Jupiter positions and velocities as

  ```
  pos:  3.996662712108880E+00,  2.938301820497121E+00, -1.017177623308866E-01,
  vel: -4.560191659347578E-03,  6.440946682361135E-03,  7.529386668190383E-05
  ```
- The normalization to a center-of-gravity frame needs to apply conservation of momentum, the mass of Jupiter is large enough that just subtracting the velocities might give physically wrong results. [*not resolved, the initial data should already be barycentric, no corrections should be necessary*]
- The varying accuracy of the physical constants will also introduce errors that will lead away from the reference positions. The most "dirty" constants that are visible at the moment are the gravitational constant and the masses, after that the uncertainty in the type of year. You only get the first two digits reliable of any (correctly) computed result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, first of all I changed the values of the variables. In this problem we want to calculate the trajectory of Sun and Jupiter as one entity in the centroid (barycentre in french) solar system. I use python 3.7 so no problem for the exponent. See above the new variables and the plot. Thank you.

Comment: The problem to solve is Orbital Motion: Two-Body Problem

Comment: Is the image a more true representation of your actual code than the code blocks? What code is producing the plot? The constant day_to_sec is missing a factor 60, at the moment you count the minutes in a day.